# SSMS crashes when Object Explorer Details is opened

Tags: azure, crash, azure-sql-database, ssms

When using SQL Server Management Studio 18.4 to access an Azure SQL server, I am able to login successfully and can expand the Databases list in Object Explorer. However, when I attempt to open Object Explorer Details, SSMS becomes unresponsive and has to be restarted.

This happens, both on my local PC and also from an Azure VM. Strangely, when using SSMS 12, I don't have a problem and can open the tables in Object Explorer Details.

When accessing a local instance of SQL Server (2017), SSMS works just fine. This is true for both my local PC and the Azure VM.

Answer (score 0):

Skip the use of SSMS 18.4 and instead try removing 18.4 in favor of using SSMS 18.3. Download SSMS 18.3.x from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15#previous-ssms-releases). SSMS 18.5 may come with a fix in a few weeks.

However, if you later plan to install SQL Server 2019, that SSMS 18.3 may prevent SQL Server from installing successfully. That is a bug in SSMS 18.3 that is fixed on SSMS 18.4. Install SQL Server 2019 first, if SQL Server 2019 is in your plans also, before installing SSMS 18.3.

Comment: I have now tried versions 18.3.1 & 17.9.1 but both are behaving the same as 18.4.

Comment: Capture a dump of the process

1. Download ProcDump and unzip it on a folder.
2. Run this command on that folder:

\procdump.exe -e -h -ma -w ssms.exe

3. Start SSMS if not started already
4. Repro issue
5. Text should appear in the cmd prompt about writing the dump file, wait for that to finish
6. Create a ZIP file withe the .dmp file and share it using OneDrive.

Please file a bug here and share the location of the ZIP file here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server

Comment: I have created a dump file using ProcDump with the syntax you specified and have uploaded to OneDrive and created a share link. I'm unsure what to do next as your 'feedback.azure...' link just takes me to a page of suggestions for improving SQL Server. Apologies if I'm being dim.

Comment: Could you share with me the URL of the public folder on OneDrive so I can share it with the SSMS team? Thank you for taking the time to create this dump.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtGmkMXuVPGgtWc9g3aWbp2Lm5T6?e=om9iPF